# Error on FormatFloat(#,##0.00, var_number) and Format('%n', var_number) Rounding-off to Thousands

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

The FormatFloat(#,##0.00, var_number) and Format('%n', var_number) is giving me a rounded-off to thousands result. Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with my code?

I did some `Minimum Reproducible Example` below for your reference. **The result I am getting here is 12 instead of 12,345.00**. Please let me know where and what exactly I missed here.

**FMX Procedure:**

```
unit Unit9;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base,
  FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf,
  FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async,
  FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.Phys.SQLite, FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteDef,
  FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs, FireDAC.FMXUI.Wait, FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS,
  FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt, Data.Bind.EngExt, Fmx.Bind.DBEngExt,
  System.Rtti, System.Bindings.Outputs, Fmx.Bind.Editors, Data.Bind.Components,
  Data.Bind.DBScope, Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client,
  FMX.ListView, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm9 = class(TForm)
    lbl1: TLabel;
    lsv1: TListView;
    con1: TFDConnection;
    qryLists: TFDQuery;
    bdr1: TBindSourceDB;
    bdl1: TBindingsList;
    tcf1: TLinkFillControlToField;
    lpfText: TLinkPropertyToField;
    qryInsert: TFDQuery;
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form9: TForm9;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm9.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qryInsert.ParamByName('id').AsInteger := 1;
  qryInsert.ParamByName('cur_datetime').AsDateTime := now;
  qryInsert.ParamByName('name').AsString := 'sample';
  qryInsert.ParamByName('size_cont').AsString := 'size_cont';
  qryInsert.ParamByName('qty').AsFloat := 10;
  qryInsert.ParamByName('est_price').AsFloat := 1234.5;
  qryInsert.ParamByName('qty_price').AsString := '10 x 1234.5';
  qryInsert.ParamByName('estimate').AsString := FormatFloat('#,##0.00', 10 * 1234.5); //the result is giving me 12 (the correct one is 12,345.00)
  qryInsert.ExecSQL;
  qryLists.Close;
  qryLists.Open();
end;

end.
```

**FMX File:**

```
object Form9: TForm9
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form9'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 308
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object lbl1: TLabel
    Align = Top
    StyledSettings = [Family, Style, FontColor]
    Size.Width = 308.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 33.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TextSettings.Font.Size = 14.000000000000000000
    TextSettings.HorzAlign = Center
    Text = '5'
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object lsv1: TListView
    ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TImageListItemBottomDetailAppearance'
    ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TImageListItemBottomDetailShowCheckAppearance'
    HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
    FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 308.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 407.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object btn1: TButton
    Align = Bottom
    Position.Y = 440.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 308.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 7
    Text = 'btn1'
    OnClick = btn1Click
  end
  object con1: TFDConnection
    Params.Strings = (
      
        'Database=D:\My Project Files\5. my_projects_aws-rest\project_x_v' +
        '0\application\client\database\smartcart.s3db'
      'LockingMode=Normal'
      'DriverID=SQLite')
    Connected = True
    LoginPrompt = False
    Left = 72
    Top = 24
  end
  object qryLists: TFDQuery
    Active = True
    Connection = con1
    SQL.Strings = (
      'SELECT id, date_created, name, size_cont, qty_price, estimate'
      'FROM lists ORDER BY date_created DESC')
    Left = 112
    Top = 24
  end
  object bdr1: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = qryLists
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 152
    Top = 24
  end
  object bdl1: TBindingsList
    Methods = <>
    OutputConverters = <>
    Left = 20
    Top = 5
    object tcf1: TLinkFillControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      Control = lsv1
      Track = True
      FillDataSource = bdr1
      AutoFill = True
      FillExpressions = <
        item
          SourceMemberName = 'estimate'
          ControlMemberName = 'Detail'
        end>
      FillHeaderExpressions = <>
      FillBreakGroups = <>
    end
    object lpfText: TLinkPropertyToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = bdr1
      FieldName = 'estimate'
      Component = lbl1
      ComponentProperty = 'Text'
    end
  end
  object qryInsert: TFDQuery
    Connection = con1
    SQL.Strings = (
      'INSERT INTO lists (id, date_created, name, size_cont, '
      '                   qty, est_price, qty_price, estimate) '
      'VALUES (:id, :cur_datetime, :name, :size_cont, '
      '        :qty, :est_price, :qty_price, :estimate);')
    Left = 192
    Top = 24
    ParamData = <
      item
        Name = 'ID'
        DataType = ftInteger
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'CUR_DATETIME'
        DataType = ftDateTime
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'NAME'
        DataType = ftString
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'SIZE_CONT'
        DataType = ftString
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'QTY'
        DataType = ftFloat
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'EST_PRICE'
        DataType = ftFloat
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'QTY_PRICE'
        DataType = ftString
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'ESTIMATE'
        DataType = ftFloat
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end>
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:** TListView Properties Screenshot

[image: TListView Properties Screenshot]

Comment: Why are you using `AsString` instead of `AsFloat`?

Comment: I think FormatFloat is a String. I am getting this error `[dcc32 Error] Unit9.pas(53): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Double' and 'string'` if I changed it to AsFloat.

Comment: You don't need FormatFloat at all. Remove it, and assign the floating point value directly tot he parameter using `AsFloat`, as in `qryInsert.ParamByName('estimate').AsFloat := 1234.5 * 10;`.

Comment: If I do that, I could no longer get the right format of my number `12,345.00`. This is the reason why I used this weird `FormatFloat`. Perhaps, do you have any other suggestion to get the format I want.

Comment: You format numbers for display to the user, not for storage in the database. Floats are stored as floats, and your value in the table is a float.

Comment: Yes you are right but TListView doesn't have property for display just like any other visual component. Unless, there is a way that I could code it and how is my other issue (see screenshot in my update).

Comment: You're making no sense. A ListView has nothing to do with storing data in a database table. I'd suggest you delete this question and start over with a clear explanation of what you're actually trying to do. I've told you several times that the issue is with using `FormatFloat` and `AsString` to work with a flaoting point type parameter, and you're now talking about a ListView.

Comment: From the RME I've given here you will find that I am using TListView to display the data using livebindings. You suggest that I should do the formatting at the user level display. So where we should display the data other than TListView.

Comment: As I've said several times, where you display it has nothing to do with the issue you've described. When you set the parameter, you need to use a floating point value instead of AsString and FormatFloat. Displaying the data is a totally different issue that is not related to the question you've asked here.

Comment: So you are referring to my question that is not clearly described. But the issue that I am raising here is valid. Is this what you are trying to say?

Comment: No. I'm saying that you're using parameter values wrong, and I've told you how to correct that issue. Now you're adding something totally different to the question that is not related to what you asked here. If you use `AsFloat` and assign the value directly as is without using `FormatFloat`, the problem you're having disappears. Formatting the value for display is a **totally different issue**. Parameters have **nothing** to do with displaying data to the user.

Comment: Probably @KenWhite is trying to say that he answered your question (His answer: Save the value as float in the database to avoid FormatFloat) and you have to ask ANOTHER question for the side effect. This question is something like "Using LiveBinding, how do I a formatted float value from a database into a TListView".

Comment: The reason you might be getting a ‘12’ instead of ‘12345’ might have to do with the users locale. Example: the dutch locale uses a comma (,) as decimal separator. So when assigning the string value of ‘12,345’ to a float field the result wilt be 12.345. If you then use that float value again en format it using something like FormatFloat(‘#,##0.00’, AsFloat), you get 12.

Comment: Regarding the E2010 error: what is the filed type of ‘estimate’ in your database...? Is it realy a float or a char/text at db level?

Comment: @R.Hoek I am using SQLite and the datatype there is `Real`. I already checked also my users locale (meaning local computer configuration) and it is in US Format.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you. I will be raising another question for this purpose. This time will be related to how I can format the number in the TListView at the user display level.

Comment: @fpiette Thank you for the explaining this to me. Like I said, I am raising another question for this.

Comment: @KenWhite Please post your answer, so I could mark it `answered'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter is defined as `Datatype = ftFloat`, according to your form definition file.

```
item
  Name = 'ESTIMATE'
  DataType = ftFloat
  ParamType = ptInput
  Value = Null
end>
```

That means that you have no need to assign the value using the parameter's `AsString` or converting it using `FormatFloat` at all, as you can just assign the value directly as a floating point value.

```
qryInsert.ParamByName('estimate').AsFloat := 10 * 1234.5;
```

Doing so cannot cause any rounding errors, as the data is stored with the proper value. No rounding is done at all.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will be posting in another question related to the issue of displaying the numbers in desired format at user interface level.